# Attachinary not allowing submit after upload Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

So after I select my files to upload, and it uploads on cloudinary, attachinary keeps my submit button disabled.

```
<input name="commit" value="[100%] Uploading..." class="btn btn-default" data-disable-with="Create Article" disabled="" type="submit">
```

Answer (score 1):

ok, found it, I had put <%= cloudinary_js_config %> in the `<head>` and not in the `<body>`